# Determinants order of operations

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

When computing determinants using their properties, what is the order in which the determinant gets evaluated? 
Ie.   \begin{vmatrix}
        2AA^t \\
        \end{vmatrix} 
Do we start with $2A$ or $A^t$?

similarly for this one:
\begin{vmatrix}
        2A^t(A^{-1})^2 \\
        \end{vmatrix} 
Do we start with $2A^t$ or $(A^{-1})^2$?

Comment: We have a fantastic property $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $$|AB| = |A| \cdot |B|$$, the order does not matter, and $$|A| \cdot |B| = |B| \cdot |A|$$ because they are just scalars.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the size (number of rows or of columns) of matrix $A$.

For the first question, I would use this before any calculation:

$$|2AA^\top|=2^n|A|\cdot |A^\top|$$
$$=2^n|A|\cdot |A|$$
$$=2^n|A|^2$$

For the second question, I would use this before any calculations:

$$|2A^\top(A^{-1})^2|=2^n|A^\top|\cdot|A^{-1}|^2$$
$$=2^n|A|\cdot|A|^{-2}$$
$$=2^n|A|^{-1}$$

Then I would do the calculations. These work due to the identities

$$|AB|=|A|\cdot |B|$$
$$|A^{-1}|=|A|^{-1}$$
$$|A^\top|=|A|$$
$$|cA|=c^n|A|$$